# Linq query with curly braces for anonymous action/function body

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have this entities:

```
public class Parent: AllDependant
{
    /*Properties goes here*/
}

public class Children: AllDependant
{
    /*Properties goes here*/
}
```

Then I have `allDependants` variable with typeof `List<AllDependant>` which will keep some of parents and childrens entitiy in mix.

Later on, I want to select from them and do something like this:

```
var selectedDependantInfos = allDependants
        .Select(dependant =>
        {
            if (dependant is Parent)
            {
                var parent = dependant as Parent;
                return new { Name = parent.Name, SomeSpecialInfo = parent.ParentInfo };
            }
            else
            {
                var child = dependant as Children;
                return new { Name = child.Name, SomeSpecialInfo = child.ChildInfo }
            }
        });
```

Note the specific property for child and parent require me to cast and get the property to a new model for UI display which is not entity concern. I cannot put the special property in AllDependant base class because I need to refactor the property name on so many files including *.ascx which is troublesome. However it done by using the Linq `Select` extension method above but I just thinking of this:

Question: How can I do the same in Linq Query?

This will give error on the `select` keyword and the curly braces:

```
var selectedDependantInfos = from dependant in allDependants
                            select
                            {
                                /* the same if statement goes here */
                            }
```

Comment: What do you think you will gain by changing it into Linq syntax?

Comment: The error is because you're missing the `new` keyword. `select new { .. }`.

Comment: @ChrisWue, not changing just thinking how to do function body in Linq query just like we can do function body in Lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the conditional operator and get something like

```
  from dependant in allDependants             
  select dependant is Parent 
         ? new { Name = (dependant as Parent).Name,  /* Parent fields */ }
         : new { Name = (dependant as Children).Name, /* Child fields */ }
```

But as you see that is not a great improvement. There's no convenient place to do the type-cast.

The better option would seem to move the Name and SpecialInfo properties to a base class (AllDependant or a special intermediate class).

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. Note that a ``Sibling`` class in ``allDependants`` will result in ``NullReferenceException`` here - ``InvalidCastException`` is always more informative, so I'd use a cast,

Comment: Thanks, almost there, but maybe I want to change the question to How can I create Linq query with action/function body instead of expression just like how we can do within Lambda using curly braces.

Comment: You can do `(from d in ...).Select(x => x)`.

Comment: I see, so it seems like not possible to have curly braces in the Linq query but after that we can combined with extension method to have function body in lambda expression. Nice.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be:

```
var parents = allDependants.OfType<Parent>.Select(p => new { Name =  p.Name, .... };
var children = allDependants.OfType<Children>.Select(c => new { Name =  c.Name, .... };

var combined = parents.Concat(children);
```

The disadvantage of this approach would be that addDependants would be iterated over twice.

Comment: This will iterate over ``allDependants`` twice and perform the type check twice but on the other hand is safe if ``allDependants`` will contain an ``AllDependant`` not being ``Parent`` or ``Child`` (as opposed to OP solution).

Comment: Oh, ya, it just alternative to my example, but it is not the answer :) actually I want to know how I can do the same by using Linq query

Comment: It is a Linq query.  Isn't it?

Comment: I mean I want to convert from using Linq extension method in the example above to Linq query using `from e in entities select e.column` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of using Reflection

```
var selectedDependantInfos = from p in allDependants
                         let key = p is Parent ? "ParentInfo" : "ChildInfo"
                         select new { 
                             Name = p.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(p, null).ToString(), 
                             SomeSpecialInfo = p.GetType().GetProperty(key).GetValue(p, null).ToString() 
                         };
```

Comment: While this might work it's not a good thing to do: performance is bad (compared to the original approach) and it's refactoring unfriendly

Comment: @ChrisWue Reflection performance will depend on the implementation. Like p.GetType().GetProperty("Name") would be cached. You can found such implementation in many ORM frameworks.